# Drivers for BSNL 3G data card( Model no : LW272 )

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a BSNL 3g data card BSNL 3G data card( Model no : LW272 ). I had installed it on my Dell Laptop(Windows 7). then for some stupid reasons i deleted the drivers of this data card.

Now when i connect data card to my system,it is not detected by the system and i am not able to use it as a modem.

I am not able to find the drivers for this data card. how can i fix my issue?

Comment: Uninstall the driver from Add/Remove Program and restart your PC and plug it in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSNL does not manufacture datacards, you need to check who is the manufacturer of the device and then you might find the driver on the manufacturer's website.
BSNL has a driver on its [site](http://www.bsnldatacard.com/bsnl-data-card-details-software-manuals-downloads.html), you can check it. It might be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you plug it in, it should appear as a CD-ROM drive in Computer.  If you click on that icon you should see an install.exe, which will reinstall the software.

(I'm not sure if I am getting confused with MTS, as I was using both on a recent trip to India, but they both worked similarly, as far as I can remember)

Comment: When i connect my Data Card nothing comes inside MyComputer, i mean neither in a Removable drive nor CD-ROM drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your data card to the system.
2. Right click on ***Computer*** and folloewed by ***Manage***.
3. Click on the ***Device Manager***
4. Find your device under ***Universal Serial Bus Controllers***
5. Click Enable if this in Disable mode.